# Not selecting my roles? - Rails 4.2, Multi Select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an edit form, where you can select multiple roles for a particular group. It does as its suppose to in terms of populating the select box and saving what you select to the database.

But when it comes to editing, while it populates correctly, it doesn't select the already selected roles. The relationship between groups and roles is as follows:

```
has_many :roles, :through => :groups_roles
```

in the groups model.

My select box is set up as such, for both edit and new views:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select roles for this group</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= f.select(:roles, options_for_select(Xaaron::Role.pluck(:role_name),
        :selected => @group.roles), {}, class: 'form-control', multiple: true) %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**So whats the deal?** On new, like I said, it populates, it lets you select, it saves what you selected. On Edit, it populates, lets you select and saves to the database, **BUT** doesn't select already chosen roles for this group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selected` is argument, not a hash option as you declared. See specification [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) for more details.

Comment: can you give a more specific example, I read the docs but I am confused.

Comment: Just pass `@group.roles` as second argument.

Comment: that did nothing. `@group.roles` is an array of active record objects, not `role_names` as we see in the `Xaaron::Role.pluck(:role_name)` but adding: `.pluck(:role_name)` worked :D